# as.matrix() and as.dist() have different results

Tags: r, matrix, hierarchical-clustering, cosine-similarity

I have a list "simil", which contains 7 vectors:

```
 > dput(simil)
structure(list(Monday = structure(c(0.889987253484581, 0.882957894295089, 
0.882232353177177, 0.874080268021168, 0.851760771472629, 0.811536071048775
), .Names = c("Sunday", "Tuesday", "Friday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Saturday")), Tuesday = structure(c(0.901682757072732, 0.882957894295089, 
0.874716806575548, 0.869202937572079, 0.855248496101086, 0.818659253763272
), .Names = c("Sunday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Friday", "Thursday", 
"Saturday")), Wednesday = structure(c(0.88354911311872, 0.874716806575548, 
0.874080268021168, 0.853293126413937, 0.851921112754124, 0.841170795359615
), .Names = c("Sunday", "Tuesday", "Monday", "Friday", "Thursday", 
"Saturday")), Thursday = structure(c(0.86579834238668, 0.855248496101086, 
0.851921112754124, 0.851760771472629, 0.851384896045153, 0.836732564057725
), .Names = c("Sunday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Monday", "Friday", 
"Saturday")), Friday = structure(c(0.882232353177177, 0.869202937572079, 
0.856441568566172, 0.853293126413937, 0.851384896045153, 0.80098779448239
), .Names = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Sunday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Saturday")), Saturday = structure(c(0.866654844262859, 0.841170795359615, 
0.836732564057725, 0.818659253763272, 0.811536071048775, 0.80098779448239
), .Names = c("Sunday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Tuesday", "Monday", 
"Friday")), Sunday = structure(c(0.901682757072732, 0.889987253484581, 
0.88354911311872, 0.866654844262859, 0.86579834238668, 0.856441568566172
), .Names = c("Tuesday", "Monday", "Wednesday", "Saturday", "Thursday", 
"Friday"))), .Names = c("Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", 
"Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"), class = c("similMatrix", "list"
))
```

I now want to transform it into a dist object to then use it for hclust(). So I use as.dist() and I compute:

```
> as.dist(simil,diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)
             Monday    Sunday   Tuesday    Friday Wednesday  Thursday  Saturday
Monday    0.0000000 0.8899873 0.8829579 0.8822324 0.8740803 0.8517608 0.8115361
Sunday    0.8899873 0.0000000 1.0000000 0.8692029 0.8747168 0.8552485 0.8186593
Tuesday   0.8829579 1.0000000 0.0000000 0.8532931 1.0000000 0.8519211 0.8411708
Friday    0.8822324 0.8692029 0.8532931 0.0000000 0.8519211 1.0000000 0.8367326
Wednesday 0.8740803 0.8747168 1.0000000 0.8519211 0.0000000 0.8513849 0.8009878
Thursday  0.8517608 0.8552485 0.8519211 1.0000000 0.8513849 0.0000000 1.0000000
Saturday  0.8115361 0.8186593 0.8411708 0.8367326 0.8009878 1.0000000 0.0000000
```

But this is a slightly different result from when I use as.matrix():

```
> as.matrix(simil)
             Monday   Tuesday Wednesday  Thursday    Friday  Saturday    Sunday
Monday    1.0000000 0.8829579 0.8740803 0.8517608 0.8822324 0.8115361 0.8899873
Sunday    0.8899873 0.9016828 0.8835491 0.8657983 0.8564416 0.8666548 1.0000000
Tuesday   0.8829579 1.0000000 0.8747168 0.8552485 0.8692029 0.8186593 0.9016828
Friday    0.8822324 0.8692029 0.8532931 0.8513849 1.0000000 0.8009878 0.8564416
Wednesday 0.8740803 0.8747168 1.0000000 0.8519211 0.8532931 0.8411708 0.8835491
Thursday  0.8517608 0.8552485 0.8519211 1.0000000 0.8513849 0.8367326 0.8657983
Saturday  0.8115361 0.8186593 0.8411708 0.8367326 0.8009878 1.0000000 0.8666548
```

With `as.dist()`, the matrix is not entirely symmetric and some pairs become wrong, which doesn't happen with `as.matrix()`. Why is that? How can I correct it?

Comment: If it is a `list` as you mentioned, `sapply/lapply` are methods to loop through the `list.  It would have been better if you post a dput of the examp;e

Comment: I have updated the question with dput(). But I don't understand, how should I use sapply/lapply to transform my list into a dist object? Isn't as.dist() supposed to do that already?

Comment: Based on your dput, the codes you used are not giving the output you showed, but, `simplify2array(simil)` gives a matrix

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you are saying, I tried regenerating the variable through dput() and I get the exact same result again.
I tried simplify2array(simil) and it also gives me a different matrix with wrong values, so it's not what I need.

Comment: it looks like you've forgot to mention an add-on package you're using. I get an error for `as.dist(simil)` : `Error in as.dist.default(simil) : 
  (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'` - and something rather pointless with `as.matrix(simil)`

Comment: That's odd, but you are right, it might be due to the fact that simil was generated through the similarity() function of the package "Quanteda", which might have added properties and extra classes to it. I found a way around (see my answer below). Thx for your help!

Comment: There are 8439 packages on CRAN - there's no way anyone would know them all. You need to mention the extra packages you're using when asking a question :)

Comment: I thought that simil was a simple list object, which is why I didn't mention that it was generated by quanteda. But I will be more careful next time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So in the end I managed to fix it by first transforming into a matrix, then swaping the row order, and finally changing into a dist object:

```
simil = as.matrix(simil)
simil = simil[ c(1,3,5,6,4,7,2),]
simil = as.dist(1-simil,diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)

> simil
              Monday    Tuesday  Wednesday   Thursday     Friday   Saturday     Sunday
Monday    0.00000000 0.11704211 0.12591973 0.14823923 0.11776765 0.18846393 0.11001275
Tuesday   0.11704211 0.00000000 0.12528319 0.14475150 0.13079706 0.18134075 0.09831724
Wednesday 0.12591973 0.12528319 0.00000000 0.14807889 0.14670687 0.15882920 0.11645089
Thursday  0.14823923 0.14475150 0.14807889 0.00000000 0.14861510 0.16326744 0.13420166
Friday    0.11776765 0.13079706 0.14670687 0.14861510 0.00000000 0.19901221 0.14355843
Saturday  0.18846393 0.18134075 0.15882920 0.16326744 0.19901221 0.00000000 0.13334516
Sunday    0.11001275 0.09831724 0.11645089 0.13420166 0.14355843 0.13334516 0.00000000
```

It might be due to the fact that "simil" was created from the similarity() function of the quanteda package.